# How to return API response status in NextJS13?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

Right now am using different ways to return API HTTP status in my NextJS-13 but nothing seems to be working for me.

***Note: I am using Typescript in my project.***

Here is my code with static 200 API response and am sending API status in body:

```
type postProps = {
  title: string;
  content?: string;
  published: boolean;
};

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const post: postProps = await request.json();
  if (!post.title) {
    return NextResponse.json({
      status: 400,
      message: "Please enter title",
    });
  }
}
```

**I have tried**

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export async function POST(response: NextApiResponse, request: NextApiRequest ) {
  const post: postProps = await request.body;
  if (!post.title) {
    return response.status(400).json({
     message: "Please enter title"
    })
  }
}
```

`But it give me  TypeError: res.status is not a function`

**I also have tried**

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export async function POST(response: Response, request: Request) {
  const post: postProps = await request.json();
  if (!post.title) {
    return response.status(400).json({
     message: "Please enter title"
    })
  }
}
```

`But it give me the following error: This expression is not callable. Type 'Number' has no call signatures.`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

NextResponse.json({
  message: "Please enter title"
}, {
  status: 400,
})
```

Comment: How to set status: 204? Got error.

Comment: Anyone from future may check this link to handle 204 error from nextjs doc, https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-api-status-body

Comment: source reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json_static#status

Answer (score -1):

you could easy access to the global object Response and do it like this:

```js
export default function Post(req: NextApiRequest) {


  return Response.json({
    message: "anything"
  }, {
    status: 200
  })
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you mixed up the order of the `request` and `response` parameters:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}
```

`request` should be first and `response` second. You're trying to access `status` on the `request` which doesn't have it.

Comment: Giving me same error with your order too.
export async function POST(request: NextApiRequest, response: NextApiResponse) {
  const post: postProps = await request.body;
  if (!post.title) {
    return response.status(400).json({
      message: "Please enter title",
    });
  }

Comment: this example worked only for nextjs version < 13